# RODBC - sqlSave - Why is so much memory being requested?

Tags: r, rodbc

I have some R code that looks as follows:

```
missingDataJson <- toJSON(head(diff))

df <- data.frame(ValidationDate = startTime, DataType = "Panel", MissingData = missingDataJson, stringsAsFactors = F)

sqlSave(odsHandle, df, tablename = "Utility.DailyDataValidation", append=T)
```

The data frame "df" looks as follows:

```
df
       ValidationDate DataType
1 2016-08-22 13:40:37    Panel
                                                                                                                                                                                       MissingData
1 {"SubId":[160822032032,160822032033,160822032034,160822032035,160822032036,160822032037],"ReadTime":[1471887657.787,1471887681.357,1471887705.023,1471887728.483,1471887752.273,1471887776.423]}
```

When I execute sqlSave, I get the following error message:

```
Error in odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  : 
  'Calloc' could not allocate memory (18446744071562067968 of 1 bytes)
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  :
  Reached total allocation of 16287Mb: see help(memory.size)
2: In odbcUpdate(channel, query, mydata, coldata[m, ], test = test,  :
  Reached total allocation of 16287Mb: see help(memory.size)
```

Why is so much memory being requested? The size of the data frame is quite small.

Comment: If you restart your R session, are you able to reproduce the error?

Comment: Yes, I actually tried that. And I also tried shutting down altogether and restarting. I get the same error.

Comment: What is the target table defined as? I ran into a similar issue where the target column was defined as "max" which equated to 2GB; R dutifully tried to allocate things correctly to transfer to a C struct to transfer to the server ... and things exploded very quickly.

Comment: @r2evans - I do have a column in the DB that is a varchar(max). How did you get around this? For R to just automatically allocate the maximum amount of memory for the column seems ridiculous.

Comment: For me it wasn't a `varchar(max)` (which I have, and they aren't a problem), it was `image(max)`. I don't disagree, but I also don't understand the underlying mechanism being used, so I can't argue much against using C structs.

Comment: @r2evans - Interesting that when I don't append, but let R create a new table, it works, but it only creates a column of varchar(255) and truncates the contents. I'm beginning to think that writing to databases is not R's forte.

Comment: Please keep in mind that the problem here is pretty clearly happening in RODBC, which is not "R" per se, but a package written for R. You might have more luck asking on r-sig-db or contacting the author of RODBC directly. (Though be warned, he has a reputation for being a bit prickly.) Also, you might try using the RSQLServer package instead; it might work better.

Comment: I'm currently transitioning a project of mine from `RODBC` to `RSQLServer` for a couple of reasons. `sqlSave` is one of them (though it is not the crux).

Comment: If you going to consider using `RSQLServer`, I'd suggest using the [Github version](https://github.com/imanuelcostigan/RSQLServer) (perhaps even the "feature-dbi-0_5" branch) which may benefit from the [Github version of `DBI`](https://github.com/rstats-db/DBI) as well. @imanuelcostigan has been busy upgrading it (and DBI is seeing many changes as well).

Comment: To add to @r2evans comments, I also moved away from RODBC (but to ROracle, as that's my backend, not by choice) for other, different issues with RODBC that I had no luck getting addressed. It looks like Hadley/Rstudio folks are working on an alternative ([odbconnect](https://github.com/hadley/odbconnect)) but it looks a ways away from an initial release.

Comment: Oh, nice find, I hadn't seen that yet. I had played with RODBCDBI but the performance hit was a deterrent. What makes you say *"it looks a ways away from an initial release"*? (Is it because its version is 0.0.0.9000? :-)